# Fullcalendar sets all events one day back

Tags: fullcalendar

I call the fullCalendar method as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                firstDay: 1,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: [{title":"Matthias Klein","start":"01-01-2014","end":"01-01-2015"},{"title":"Matthias Klein","start":"01-01-2014","end":"02-01-2014"},{"title":"Matthias Klein","start":"01-01-2014","end":"01-01-2014"}]
            });

        });
```

But in the result all events starting and ending one day before at 2:46a:

[see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCjn1.jpg)

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Few things,

Try changing your date format for your events to yyyy-mm-dd I had this issue last night where my events were all showing at 4;30pm the day before and this fixed it for me. 

Also noticed your dates have no times so are they all day events? If so make sure you're setting the allDay property to true.

One last thing, firstDay means the day of the week, so if Monday is 0 then Tuesday is 1. It doesn't mean the first day of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things,

Try changing your date format for your events to yyyy-mm-dd I had this issue last night where my events were all showing at 4;30pm the day before and this fixed it for me.

Also noticed your dates have no times so are they all day events? If so make sure you're setting the allDay property to true.

One last thing, firstDay means the day of the week, so if Monday is 0 then Tuesday is 1. It doesn't mean the first day of the month.

Comment: One more issue. I call it now as follows:                 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ allDayDefault: true, firstDay: 1, eventLimit: true, events: [{"title":"Matthias Klein","start":"2014-10-31","end":"2014-11-03"}] }); But in the calendar view it just shows the event on 2014-10-31 until 2014-11-02 ([link](http://imgur.com/9afyjHd))

Comment: Did you set allDay to true?

Comment: I set the allDayDefault to true. Do I have to do it for every event?

Comment: yes each event should have it. I haven't heard of allDayDefault where did you find that?

Comment: I found it here ([link](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/)). Sorry, but setting allDay to true for every event didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Few things, looking at http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
1) Make sure allDay true is not in quotes. 2) If you look at the end property the note states "It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example, if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the event will be 00:00:00 on Friday!" perhaps adding midnight or some sort of time value to your date values may fix your issue? I've always used FullCalendar with a full datetime string, so not sure how it works with just a date.

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest, looks valid to me. I'd suggest using full datetime strings.

Comment: Ok. I didn't see this information. My way of thinking is a bit different but ok. Now I just add 1 day at the end date every time I get it from the DB. I use @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.vacationdaysEvents)) to create my json response from an array (ASP.NET MVC). I mean it works. But do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Setting the allDay property to true didn't fix it, and changing the date format of the events to yyyy-mm-dd stopped it from working altogether - it only seems to accept MM/dd/yyyy now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was only able to solve it by following the EXACT date format given on the [demo page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals-demo)...

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` (for example **2019-05-08T16:00:00** is 4 o'clock today)

or

`yyyy-MM-dd` (for example **2019-05-08** is today)

In other words, U.S. date format plus 24-hour time format.

Unfortunately there does seem to be a bug with [nextDayThreshold](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold). If it's set to 00:00:00 (the default), events ending at this time will be displayed as having ended the day before, which contradicts the documentation. Also, `allDay=true` events spanning more than one day will always be displayed as ending on the previous day.

Here's my full code...

```
addEvents = [];

addEvents.push({
    title: "First Event",
    url: "http://localhost:11634/events/141",
    start: '2019-05-19T09:00:00',
    end: '2019-05-19T13:00:00'});   

addEvents.push({
    title: "Second Event",
    url: "http://localhost:11634/events/137",
    start: '2019-11-02',
    end: '2019-11-02'});         

addEvents.push({
    title: "Third, multi-day event",
    url: "http://localhost:11634/events/115",
    start: '2019-11-08T00:00:00',
    end: '2019-11-10T01:00:00'});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['dayGrid'],
        events: addEvents
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix that: use nextDayThreshold parameter

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       **nextDayThreshold**: '00:00:00', // 9am
```

nextDayThreshold set the minimum time it must be in order for it to render as if it were on that day.

Comment: I can see this could make a difference if each event went into the NEXT day, however it's not gonna fix events being displayed a day early.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue and in my application it appears to be a timezone problem. When making the round trip to by database and back, the Date object appears to pick up timezone information, which screws up the calendar...